# bootstrap-multiselect gets clipped under kendo window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect, kendo-window

I have kendo window and i'm using [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) dropdownlist inside kendo window. When i click on drop down list to select something, the dropdown-menu clips under the window and i can't see all the options.

I have tried setting the z-index of dropdown-menu but its not working

```
.dropdown-menu
{
  z-index:50000;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:250px;
}
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da0ywy8z/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to alter the `overflow` property on the modal window, which is currently set to `auto`, which will hide any overflow and add a scrollbar. To make the menu visible outside of the window, set `overflow` to `visible`

```
div.k-window-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/da0ywy8z/2/